# Postgres in docker connection via IntelliJ works but not via other container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have following docker compose file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:

  app-db:
    build: ./db
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes_from:
      - app-db-data

  app-db-data:
    image: cogniteev/echo
    command: echo 'Data Container for PostgreSQL'
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data

  app-web:
    build: ./web
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - app-db
```

But when I build this and run this, app-web can't connect to the app-db. When I remove the app-web and just run my app through IntelliJ and connect to the app-db container there is no issue. They have both the same hibernate.cfg.xml so nothing different there. This is the connection url from hibernate jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tm.
Does anybody know what's going wrong?

Comment: Because the db is running in a separate container from app-web, it is not at localhost.  The url of the db is app-db.

Comment: ooh god thank you, that did the trick